# va_start/end on MacOS

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

I've moved My Android project with native part from Linux development desktop (Ubuntu 12.10 + Google's ADT bundle) to Mac (10.8.4 + Google's ADT bundle).

I use va_start/end macros in native logger class.
They worked well on Linux (stdarg.h is included), and Unfortunately get broken on Mac.
While I'm able to declare va_list variable, va_start and va_end are unresolvable by Eclipse.

I saw a lot of questions about va_start/end, but no one relay to MacOS.

How to make them work?
Thanks.

Comment: Does the code compile fine? It might just be the eclipse indexer

Comment: no. I got errors: Function va_XXX could not be resolved.

Comment: Where are you seeing the errors? What happens if you build by command line?

Comment: I see errors in Eclipse problem tab. Didn't try to build with command line tools. But just checked and there are no this errors in eclipse build console. So looks like only Eclipse thinks that something wrong.

Comment: I deleted errors and run app on device, all work well.
Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse indexing is buggy. You can disable it in preferences if you don't need it and want to get rid of the errors. Otherwise you might have to search around for a hack to fix your particular error...